# xCode OSx: Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchman

Everytime I try build in xcode I get the error too many open files, watch.

I've tried to install watchman to help with this but still no luck, also tried to link StoreKit.framework in my 'Link Binary With Libraries' but still no luck.

Below is the error that shows in the terminal when I try build my app. I also get another error which is

```
Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RNS3TransferUtility


 mobile-app/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:143:12)
        at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:133:12) {
      errno: -24,
      syscall: 'watch',
      code: 'EMFILE',
      filename: null
    }
```

Would like some ad

Comment: Google tells me that your undefined symbol is from something called React Native Transfer Utility.  Something in what you're building needs you to link that in.

Comment: I followed this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-transfer but still no luck